# Adding a subview to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, addsubview

I'm trying to add a customBadge as a subview of a UIButton -

this is my code so far -

```
//msg count initiaition
//CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"2"];
CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"2"
                                               withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                                withBadgeFrame:YES
                                           withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                                     withScale:2.0
                                                   withShining:YES];

    // Set Position of Badge 1
[customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-customBadge1.frame.size.width/2+_MsgHeadBtn.frame.size.width/2, 110, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];
 //add badge to view
[_MsgHeadBtn addSubview:customBadge1];
```

The button I'm trying to add the subview to is _MsgHeadBtn, which is the email icon on top LH of the screenshot below.
I was trying to make the custom badge appear slighty above and to the right of the email icon - but I end up with the result in the screenshot!

[image]

Can anyone offer any advice as to where i'm going wrong!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is within your `setFrame:` method. You are using `self.view.frame.size.width`.

Check with this code:

```
[customBadge1 setCenter:CGPointMake(_MsgHeadBtn.frame.size.width, 0)];
[_MsgHeadBtn addSubview:customBadge1];
```

or

```
[customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(_MsgHeadBtn.frame.size.width, 0, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];
[_MsgHeadBtn addSubview:customBadge1];
```

Comment: I would say: `    [customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(_MsgHeadBtn.frame.size.width, 0, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];`

Comment: @sergio: Thanks for the info. I just modified my answer :)

Comment: @Dancer: With pleasure, when you add subView, it's frame will be calculated based on it's parent's frame.

Comment: @Dancer: if clicked, you can get the instance in the IBAction method using - (IBAction)click:(UIButton *)sender{//sender is the clicked button}

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your frame like below:

```
[customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(_MsgHeadBtn.frame.size.width-customBadge1.frame.size.width,-customBadge1.frame.size.height/2, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];
```