# How to Create a UITextField to accommodate value in this following manner?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am developing an ios application that has two input fields that for entering date. I am planning to add a UIDatePicker in the following manner

`[_datePicker setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-_datePicker.bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-_datePicker.bounds.size.height, _datePicker.frame.size.width, _datePicker.frame.size.height)];
_inputText.inputView=_datePicker;`

But the bigger problem is, I need it to look something like the image I have posted
[image: The planned look of the date view]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: is this one or two questions?  and have you considered having three labels within one view, one having a dramatically larger font size?

Comment: I did consider the view part.. But was sort of confused about implementing a delegate to it..

Comment: sure, you can set a delegate, but why would you need a delegate for the view or labels?  you're simply setting the label's values from the date picker, right?

Comment: I need a condition for popping in the datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... there should be a couple ways to solve this.

1)

Put a transparent (or clear colored) UIButton *over* the view with the date labels.  You may need to make the view containing the labels change color/alpha something to indicate the button has been touched before bringing up the date picker.

2)

If the above doesn't work, [try adding the view with the labels as a subview into UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704755/adding-a-subview-to-uibutton).